# Error SQL0418 La utilización de marcador de parámetro no es válida

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, db2, as400

Tengo el siguiente problema

Estoy construyendo una api Rest en spring Boot, en la interface Repositorio tengo el siguiente @Query:

```java
@Query(value = "select RESCTA AS CUENTA , (NC00DB - NC00CR) AS SALDO00, NC01DB AS DEBENE, NC01CR AS CREENE, NC02DB AS DEBFEB, NC02CR AS CREFEB FROM CTBRES WHERE RESSUC = '01' AND RESAÑO = ?1 AND RESCTA BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3 AND SUBSTRING (RESCTA,?4, 1) = ' ')", nativeQuery=true)
List<BalanceCuentaModel> findSimple(@Param("anio") String anio,@Param("cuentaDesde") String cuentaDesde,@Param("cuentaHasta") String cuentaHasta,@Param("nivel") String nivel);
```

El problema está en el parámetro `?4`, `(SUBSTRING (RESCTA,?4, 1) = ' '))`, cuando pruebo el servicio desde postman me arroja la siguiente excepción:

```
could not prepare statement [[SQL0418] La utilización de marcador de parámetro no es válida.]
```

Pero si cambio el parametro `?4` por un valor cualquiera(por ejemplo el 7) si funciona perfectamente.

Esta api se conecta a `AS400` (IBM), es la primera vez que hago unaconexión de este estilo.

Desde ya gracias por su ayuda